# How do I restart content without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a quick JS web-application, and I want to be able to restart the application without actually reloading the webpage. This way, the browser won't need to get the resources again every time they want to restart the app and they can restart without internet access.

Comment: "Restarting" it could mean a lot of things, depending on what your code is actually doing. So, please post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: I was looking for something that is like window.location.reload(), but just reloads the content of the page without having to require resources from the web-page.

Answer (score 1):

Reset all of your values to their defaults, similar to what you'd do in your `init`, for example

```
var currentState,    // how things are
    defaultState = { // how things start
        count: 0
    };

function reset() { // make things how they start
    currentState = {};
    for (var key in defaultState) {
        currentState[key] = defaultState[key];
    }
}
function init() { // first time setup
    reset();
}
function count() {
    return ++currentState.count;
}
init(); // prepare everything
// have fun
count(); count(); count(); count(); // 4
// go back
reset();
count(); // 1
```

Of course, if you're manipulating the *DOM*, rebuilding the original state will involve a little more work than a simple `a = b;`

Comment: So using this solution just means that I am just manually resetting the webpage. There is no predefined version of this in the DOM, that just reloads one element?

Comment: The pre-defined one is `window.location.reload`, but whilst this will re-load what it can from the _browser's cache_, we don't know what else you have going on (maybe you've cached some data through ajax, you're sending no-cache headers or an extremely complex and time consuming start up generating primes or something? lol) and doing it manually this way means that the memory isn't cleared at all unless you explicitly clear things.

Comment: If you are going down this route, try to keep everything in your own namespace and clean up any timeouts too, so that variables don't run away on you. It will make debugging so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.location.reload()` to reload the page from cache.

A better solution of course would be to reset your variables, but we can't help you with this without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.reload(false);
```

The `false` flag will re-execute the website without reloading anything from the web which is cached locally. You can also pass `true` which will reload all resources.

Comment: location.reload() has no parameter - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload#location.reload_has_no_parameter