# How to reset a webpage with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with some programming that I want to perform..

On my page there is a button called "resetButton" and it is invisible button in the middle of the page.  It is using: `z-index: 100` to be place in front of the images that appear behind it to appear to have the effect that you are actually clicking the image to perform the action.

This buttons functionality is to reset the entire race, including: the stoplight switching back to red, the winner image going away, and the two participants in the race begin again at the starting position.

I feel as I am just overthinking this problem and cannot figure it out and would appreciate being led in the right direction.

```js
// script to show and hide winner

function showFish() {
  document.getElementById('bluefishwin').style.visibility = "visible";
}

function showTurtle() {
  document.getElementById('turtlewins').style.visibility = "visible";
}

function showFishText() {
  document.getElementById('fishwins').style.visibility = "visible";
}

function showTurtleText() {
  document.getElementById('turtlewinss').style.visibility = "visible";
}

// script to call both functions to start race

function letsRace() {
  startTimer();
  myMove();
}

// script for stoplight

function displayNextImage() {
  document.getElementById("stoplight").src = images[1];
}

function startTimer() {
  setInterval(displayNextImage);
}

var images = [],
  x = -1;
images[0] = "http://www.drivingtesttips.biz/images/traffic-light-red.jpg";
images[1] = "http://www.drivingtesttips.biz/images/traffic-lights-green.jpg";

// script for race

function myMove() {
  var elemBluefish = document.getElementById("bluefish");
  var elemTurtle = document.getElementById("turtle");

  var posBluefish = 0;
  var posTurtle = 0;

  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

  function frame() {
    if (posBluefish >= 1150 && posTurtle >= 1150) {
      clearInterval(id);
      return;
    }

    if (posBluefish < 1140) {
      posBluefish += Math.round(Math.random() * 5);

      if (posBluefish > 1140) {
        posBluefish = 1140;
      }
      elemBluefish.style.left = posBluefish + 'px';
    }

    if (posTurtle < 1140) {
      posTurtle += Math.round(Math.random() * 5);

      if (posTurtle > 1140) {
        posTurtle = 1140;
      }
      elemTurtle.style.left = posTurtle + 'px';
    }

    if (posBluefish >= 1140 || posTurtle >= 1140) {
      clearInterval(id);

      if (posBluefish >= 1140 && posTurtle < 1140) {
        showFish();
        showFishText();
      } else if (posBluefish < 1140 && posTurtle >= 1140) {
        showTurtle();
        showTurtleText();
      } else {
        window.alert("Tie");
      }
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#racePrompt {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10pc;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.raceButton {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5pc;
  right: 82pc;
  height: 10pc;
  z-index: 100;
  background: transparent;
  border: none !important;
  font-size: 0;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#myStoplight {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10pc;
}
#bluefish {
  position: absolute;
  top: 31pc;
  width: 17pc;
  left: -.5pc;
}
#turtle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15pc;
  top: 20pc;
  left: .5pc;
}
body {
  background-image: url("http://www.hpud.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/WaterBackground2.jpg")
}
.finishline {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12pc;
  top: 18pc;
}
#stoplight {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10pc;
}
#bluefishwin {
  position: absolute;
  right: 31pc;
  top: 12pc;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#turtlewins {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20pc;
  right: 35pc;
  top: 15pc;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#fishwins {
  font-size: 3pc;
  position: absolute;
  right: 35pc;
  top: 25pc;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#turtlewinss {
  font-size: 3pc;
  position: absolute;
  right: 34pc;
  top: 26pc;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="letsRace()" class="raceButton">
<img id="stoplight" src="http://www.drivingtesttips.biz/images/traffic-light-red.jpg" />
<p id="fishwins">The Fish Wins!</p>
<p id="turtlewinss">The Turtle Wins!</p>
<p id="racePrompt">Click anywhere on the light to start the race!</p>

<img id="bluefish" src="http://clipartist.net/openclipart.org/2013/July/Blue_Fish_Goldfish.png">
<img id="turtle" src="http://www.clipartkid.com/images/386/turtle-free-stock-photo-illustration-of-a-green-sea-turtle-uPgZrm-clipart.png">
<img src="https://t1.rbxcdn.com/877010da8ce131dfcb3fa6a9b07fea89" class="finishline">

<img id="bluefishwin" src="http://clipartist.net/openclipart.org/2013/July/Blue_Fish_Goldfish.png">
<img id="turtlewins" src="http://www.clipartkid.com/images/386/turtle-free-stock-photo-illustration-of-a-green-sea-turtle-uPgZrm-clipart.png">

<div id="container">
  <div id="animate"></div>
```

Any ideas on how to create a function so when I call it with an onClick I can reset everything back to as if I just rendered the page, similar to hitting the refresh button on the web browser.

Comment: `location.reload()`

Comment: @SLaks where do i add this into my code?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795248/how-do-i-restart-content-without-refreshing-the-page) which gives you a couple options.

Comment: thanks @JohnWu i solved it from here!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this practically impossible.

In order to make this work you would have to move state out of the DOM.

To do that, you must specified the Model of you application and just let the UI to render around it. You can imagine it like this:

```
var ui = createDOM(state)

body.innerHTML = ''
body.appendChild(ui)

//and you state might look like
var state = {
  players: [{id: 'turle', winner: true}]
}

//in createDOM fn
function createDOM(state) {
  var turtleWinnerDiv = document.createElement('div') 
  if (state.players[0].winner) {
    turtleWinnerDiv.style.visibility = 'visible'
  }

  return turtleWinnerDiv  
}
```

This is like "nic" way of doing this.

Uglier one might be something like this:

```
// save original app DOM
var defaultHTML = document.body.innerHTML
// at the end
document.body.innerHTML = defaultHTML
// voila App is back to default state
```